# SSRS: Pulling report only for user currently logged in

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I was needing to be able to pull a report based on who was logged in. For example, out of a group of salespeople, if Bob goes into this report and clicks on the Salesperson drop-down, I need him to only be able to see Bob as an available salesperson, not anyone else. I solved this by using the `=User!UserID` function in SSRS and it works beautifully.

Where I'm now having trouble is giving this functionality a CASE statement to allow an "Admin" view for managers to be able to go in and see Bob as well as everyone else. My current query looks like this and works as intended for only selecting that user's name from the Salesperson drop-down:

```
select SalesPerson_Name
from Salesperson
where salesperson_id =  SUBSTRING(@user,14,20)
```

[image]

Here is what I'm attempting to use to override and give an 'All' type view for Admin level:

```
select Salesperson_name
from Salesperson
where case
    when @user in ('DOMAIN\Brandyj','DOMAIN\jwilson') then 1=1
    else SalesPerson_id = SUBSTRING(@user,14,20)
    end
```

It does not like what I'm trying to do and gives me a

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Maybe I've been looking at this too long. Can someone spot something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close... just a minor change. You need the `CASE` *expression* to be evaluated on your operand of your SalesPerson_id column. `CASE` doesn't provide logical flow as you attempted to use it. Remember, it evaluates a set of boolean expressions to determine the result (which must be a single datatype).

I also opted for `OR` but you can still use `IN` if you'd like.

```
select Salesperson_name
from Salesperson
where 
    SalesPerson_id  = 
        case
            when @user = 'DOMAIN\Brandyj' or @user = 'DOMAIN\jwilson' then SalesPerson_id  
            else SUBSTRING(@user,14,20)
         end
```

Comment: *facepalm* I really thought I had it right in this context. I was treating the CASE as a switch, so functionally, the query would flow as WHERE...@USER IN... or WHERE...SALESPERSON_ID =...

I hope that makes sense. Clearly I'm wrong, so I will go over this and learn from it. Thank you!