# Blazor, SSRS Report: How can I get a report based on the current user

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a Blazor project with SSRS as the Reporting Tool. I want users when generating the report, can only get reports according to what group/branch he belongs to.

Like if the belongs to Group A/Branch A, as he logs into my project and generates a report, He can only get the reports from that Group.

Comment: how are you interacting with ssrs? how are users authenticating in your application? by 'only get reports from that group', do you mean individual reports are tied to a group, or you need the results of the reports to be filtered based on the grouping?

Comment: Maybe you can try to refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033856/ssrs-pulling-report-only-for-user-currently-logged-in) and learn how to filter report with user data.